# Access JavaScript file in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

i am relatively new to Angular and wanted to know the best way to access this **JS** file in a **html** file.

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'Z',
        scope: {
            info: '!='
        },
        templateUrl: 'abc.edu'
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you ask in a specific question with code provided ?

Comment: The above is the code to a JavaScript file that I wish to access in a HTML file. My question is how do I do so?

Comment: Have you even read the angular [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)?

Answer (score -1):

*If I understand your issue correctly*

In the HTML-file, use following:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

"myscripts.js" - can be changed to what ever you want.

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Good luck! If you are able to do and the answer did help please vote my answer.